# Subgroup generated by a subset of the group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove the set $A = \{a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2}\cdots a_n^{m_n}\mid m_i \in \mathbb{Z} \textrm{ and } 1 \leq i \leq n \}$ is equal to the set $\displaystyle \bigcap_{H \in \mathbb{\mathscr{L}}} H$
where $\mathscr{L}$ is the collection of all subgroups $H$ of $G$ that contains the set $S = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$

For the first inclusion it was okay, it's easy to show that

$A \subset \displaystyle \bigcap_{H \in \mathbb{\mathscr{L}}} H$ , since $S \subset H$ and $H$ is a subgroup, so we can operate the elements $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ and find another element in $H$.

But I'm having some issues in the second inclusion.

We consider some $k \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{H \in \mathbb{\mathscr{L}}} H$, if $k \in A$, it means that $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ that contains $S.$

My attempt was the One-step test for subgroups,

$x, y \in A \implies xy^{-1} \in A$, so $A \leq G$

We consider $x,y \in A$, it follows that

$x = a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2}\cdots a_n^{m_n}$

$y = a_1^{l_1}a_2^{l_2}\cdots a_n^{l_n}$, with $m_i, l_i \in \mathbb{Z}$

Because of the sock-shoes property we have that

$y^{-1} = a_n^{-l_n}a_{n-1}^{-l_{n-1}}\cdots a_1^{-l_1}$

Then we have to show that

$xy^{-1} \in A$, I got stuck here, because for me it seems that I need some commutative property here.

That's the right way to solve this problem? if it's not, how can I show it? Don't give the answer please, just some tips.

Comment: I don’t think that these sets are equal. $a_2a_1$ is not in $A$ but it is in the intersection.

Comment: Show that $A$ is a subgroup that contains $S$ to conclude that the intersection is contained in $A$; then show that every element of $A$ is in each subgroup that contains $S$.

Answer (score 1):

To try and furnish you with some hints, as you request:

- first of all, the only proper and rigorous way to define your set $A$ -- for which I will use another symbol, due to reasons of personal syntactic preference -- is as follows:

$$H\colon=\left\{x \in G \mid\ (\exists n, t, m)\left(n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge t \in S^n \wedge m \in \mathbb{Z}^n \wedge x=\prod_{k=1}^nt_k^{m_k}\right)\right\},$$
where it must be specified that by default any product of the form $\displaystyle\prod_{k=p}^qy_k$ -- of a family $y \in G^{[p, q]}$ indexed by the *natural* interval $[p, q]$ -- is considered with respect to the standard order on the specified interval $[p, q]$ (this needs to be mentioned because in general within a not necessarily commutative monoid $M$ one needs to specify a total order $T$ on the index set $I$ of any family $x \in M^{(I)}$ of finite support, family the product of which one would like to consider; in a general monoid, different total orders on the same index set easily lead to different values of the product of one and the same family).

- second, we introduce $H'\colon=\langle S \rangle=\displaystyle\bigcap_{\substack{F \leqslant G \\ F \supseteq S}} F$, by definition the subgroup generated by $S$. As you remarked, the inclusion $H \subseteq H'$ is easy to obtain, since $H'$ being a subgroup is multiplicatively stable and also closed with respect to inverses.
- in order to infer the reverse inclusion, you must follow the indications in the above comment of Arturo Magidin and first establish that $H \leqslant G$ is itself a subgroup such that $S \subseteq H$. The fact that $S$ is included in $H$ is a trivial observation, since for any $t \in S$ you have the family $s\colon=\{(1, t)\} \in S^{1}$ together with the family of exponents $m\colon=\{(1, 1)\} \in \mathbb{Z}^1$ such that $t=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^1s_k^{m_k}$.
- as to why $H$ is a subgroup, notice first it is clearly nonempty because $1_G \in H$ (the unity can be expressed as the product of the *empty* family of elements of $S$). It is multiplicatively stable because $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^ms_k^{p_k}\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^nt_k^{q_k}$ -- with both families $s \in S^m, t \in S^n$ consisting of elements of $S$ -- can be equivalently expressed as the product of a family in $S^{m+n}$ (I will let you figure out how) and finally closure with respect to inverses is due to a similar token: in general you have $\left(\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^nt_k^{m_k}\right)^{-1}=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^nt_{n+1-k}^{-m_{n+1-k}}$, and as long as $t \in S^n$ is a family of elements of $S$ the "reversed" family $t'\colon=\left(t_{n+1-k}\right)_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \in S^n$ clearly also is a family of elements of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Please check again the question.
As stated by @NL1992, $a_2a_1\notin A$ but $a_2a_1\in \bigcap_{H \in \mathbb{\mathscr{L}}} H$. Unless $a_ia_j=a_ja_i$ for all $a_i,a_j\in S$,  otherwise these two sets may not be equal.

The correct version of $A$ should be
$$A=\{g_1^{m_1}\dots g_k^{m_k}:k\geq 1,m_1,\dots,m_k\in \Bbb{Z},g_1,\dots g_k\in S\}.$$

You can first show that $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $S$. Since $\bigcap_{H \in \mathbb{\mathscr{L}}}H $ is the intersection of all subgroups containing $S$, we must have $A\subseteq \bigcap_{H \in \mathbb{\mathscr{L}}}H $.

Comment: That is unfortunately *not* the correct definition of $A$, as it entails $A=\varnothing$ in the particular case $S=\varnothing$. The correct and rigorous definition of $A$ can be found below in my answer.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ But the OP had already stated that $S=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ which means that $S$ is nonempty.

Comment: Even with the specification $S=\{a_k\}_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n}$, it could still very well be that $n=0$, case in which the family $a$ is empty and its set of components $S$ is accordingly also empty. Leaving that aside, on a more general note, any answer to this question is deserving of being formulated in the most comprehensive of generalities, thus including the case when $S=\varnothing$. As a final note, the family of elements $a$ which make up $S$ is completely superfluous in this instance (*to be cont.*)

Comment: (*cont.*) and it only complicates the syntax of the problem. A correct formulation of the problem would be "given subset $S \subseteq G$, the subgroup it generates can be described by etc", without any need to pointlessly involve any family of elements. Even if an unexperienced poster might phrase his question in a fashion that leaves something to be desired, one of the duties of those who post answers should be to try and deliver answers which also serve as a model of correct and proper use of syntax.